# What is the finest measurement in the Talmud?

Tags: halacha-theory, shiurim-measurements

The standard Talmudic [measures of length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_and_Talmudic_units_of_measurement#Length_and_distance) include, for example, Amah, Tefach, and Etzbah. But those measures are pretty loose, around 20% of freedom.

What object or usage, in our Halacha, requires the finest (most precise/exact) measurement, like "2 Amah and 2.549 Etzbah"?

Comment: Probably the Mizbeach. But I don't really understand what you're asking. Precision is relative to size, no? What does "finest" mean? Like relative error? Sig figs?

Comment: Occasionally an extra Kortov (5cc) will make or break it... and sometimes you have a hairbreadth - like in Safruth.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Interesting, are those measured, or theoretical only?

Comment: not sure what you mean - how do you learn: משנה מקואות ז׳:ה׳
שְׁלשָׁה לֻגִּין מַיִם, וְנָפַל לְתוֹכָן קֹרְטוֹב יַיִן, וַהֲרֵי מַרְאֵיהֶן כְּמַרְאֵה הַיַּיִן, וְנָפְלוּ לְמִקְוֶה, לֹא פְסָלוּהוּ....שְׁלשָׁה לֻגִּין מַיִם חָסֵר קֹרְטוֹב, וְנָפַל לְתוֹכָן קֹרְטוֹב חָלָב, וַהֲרֵי מַרְאֵיהֶן כְּמַרְאֵה הַמַּיִם, וְנָפְלוּ לְמִקְוֶה, לֹא פְסָלוּהוּ. are those measured, or theoretical only?

Comment: @danny better to cite menachot 12 4

Comment: What do you mean by “20% of freedom”? If you’re a Chazon Ishnik and hold an amah is 2 feet, your daled amos (really 5.6) are 10.2 feet. You can’t say “20% freedom” and claim 12.24 feet.

Comment: @DonielF - there is a difference between the vagueness built into a particular shitah, and the vargueness because no one has settled a dispute between shitos.

Comment: Total tangent: I don't know what an ammah should be lehalakhah today, but we can measure an ammah at the time of Chizqiyahu. The water tunnel between Mei Shiloach and the Old City is 535 m long, and the sign written by the workers who dug it says it was 1200 amos. Assuming rounding, that tells us that 535 m is somewhere between 1150 and 1250 amos. Or, that an ammah is between 16.8" and 18.3". Of today's shitos, R Chaim Naeh's and the Rambam's are in range.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, many of those measurements are precise!

(So, rather than answer your question, I wish to explain how it is based on a wrong assumption.)

In terms of how far one may walk on Shabbos, or how far one may carry something outside an eruv, one uses one's own ammah. Measure from your elbow to the tip of your middle finger. That's your ammah.

So, for example, my oldest son who is 6'2" is permitted to walk further from the city than his 5'3" dad can.

Where these body-based measures become imprecise is when the halakhah has to be applied to a community.

So, taking eruv for an example... Eruv is an interesting case because it is one halakhah that uses the ammah two different ways. A wall in an eruv cannot have a 10 ammah gap, so when it comes to a gaps, bigger measures are a leniency. A lintel (mavui) must run 4 amos to count as a "form of a doorway" (tzuras hapesach), and can't be 20 amos high. So that long measure would also be a stringency in length, but a leniency in height.

In a single eruv, the definition of ammah must be consistent.

More that that, according to the Rashba, the Ritva, and probably Rashi, each law has to be consistent, not just each situation. In other words, all our eruvim must use the same amamah -- even if for one eruv, the larger ammah is a leniency (eg it has gaps) and for another, larger is a stringency (eg the poles are close together).

So, for that eruv lintel, or for sukkah, one consistently uses a narrower estimate. But, since in kelaim (the laws of not planting crops together) most times wide measuring would be the more stringent, one always uses wide measures in kelaim.

Source: [Arukh haShulchan Orakh Chaim 363:32-35](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.363.32-35)

Bottom line: the imprecision appears to boil down to demographics -- no two people are alike, but we often need one halachic ruling across an entire community.

Comment: Interesting answer.